# Handwriting Controls similar to Journal

Tags: c#, winforms, tablet-pc, handwriting

We are looking for a handwriting control with similar functionality as journal.  We would use journal if I could find a way to embed it into a winform.  We used Agilix Infinotes however it is buggy when you have 8+ pages of notes written up, not to mention very slow at converting to text.  They have apparently stopped supporting infinotes.  Has anyone got anything they use for handwriting on a tablet that has similar features (Look and Feel) to journal? Or do you know of a way to use journal inside an application where we control the convert to text and saving/passing of data.

Answer (score 1):

It is well supported by .NET on tablet PCs.  Take a look at the Microsoft.Ink namespace.

Comment: We have resorted to that for now, what the users liked was in journal when you Convert to Text, you get a dialog with the original handwriting, the converted text, and alternate words.  Inifinotes also does this well however we can't use it because its too slow with 8+ pages and sometimes it crashes trying to convert to text.